# Невидимый слот в дочернем классе (No such slot)

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

есть следующий код:

**Game.h**

```
class Game : public QGraphicsView {
public:
    Game(QWidget * parent = NULL);
    void showSplashScreen();
    //void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent * event);

QGraphicsScene * scene;
TileMap * map;
int health;
int wave;
int money;

public slots:
    void showMainMenu();
    void chooseLevelMenu();
    void start();
};
```

**Часть Game.cpp**

```
...
void Game::showSplashScreen() {
setBackgroundBrush(QBrush(QImage(":/img/img/SplashScreen.jpg")));
QTimer::singleShot(3000, this, SLOT(showMainMenu()));
}
...
```

По задумке *showSplashScreen() через три секунды должен вызывать showMainMenu()*, но все ломается с ошибкой

```
QObject::connect: No such slot QGraphicsView::showMainMenu() in ..\Game.cpp:17
```

Как и было предложено ранее на подобные вопросы, я попытался добавить Q_OBJECT, но все опять сломалось, на этот раз с ошибкой

```
D:\User\Desktop\Defender\Game.cpp:8: error: 'QObject' is an ambiguous base of 'Game'
```

Как мне решить эту проблему? Заранее спасибо)

Comment: попробуйте `QTimer::singleShot(3000, this, &Game::showMainMenu));`

Comment: @BeardedBeaver здравствуйте, не помогло: `QObject::connect: No such slot QGraphicsView::&Game::showMainMenu() in ..\Game.cpp:14`

Comment: Очень странное сообщение об ошибке. Вы точно привели весь код объявления класса `Game`? По всем симптомам у вас `Game` множественно наследуется от `QObject`

Comment: @BeardedBeaver Код весь, выше только `#include`, но я сейчас заметил, что вторая ошибка, которую я указал в вопросе, видимо, возникала из-за того, что с `QGraphicsPixmapItem` я параллельно подключал `QObject`. Если же в код выше в начале просто дописать Q_OBJECT то возникает ошибка `undefined reference to vtable for Game`

Comment: `undefined reference to vtable for Game` решается просто, руками qmake запустите

Comment: @BeardedBeaver да, всё заработало. Очень глупая ошибка, ну да ладно, спасибо)